# Chinese typing in wpf textbox setting text even before OnPreviewKeyDown event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-properties, chinese-locale

I am working on **wpf** legacy code and found strange issue. We are using **custom control** TimePicker inherits from Textbox. We used **dependency property** to validate time and mask with default value like _ *:* _. It is working fine with English digits/fonts, but if I change language input to **Chinese** (in **windows 10**) then it behave differently.

```
class TimePicker : TextBox 

    static TimePicker()
    {
        // to receive coercion callback when Text property got changed
        InputMaskProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("InputMask",
           typeof(string), typeof(TimePicker),
           new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(InputMask_Changed,
           new CoerceValueCallback(OnCoerceValueChange)));
    }
```

**Expected behavior** in general that when user hit keyboard then below event get raised :

```
protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
```

And here only I am setting some value like this.Text = "some value" in above event than it is invoking below event which is actually CoerceValueCallback:

```
  private static object OnCoerceValueChange(DependencyObject obj, object value)
```

All is fine if I use English font, it called in above mentioned manner, but if I change culture / Input language in windows 10 to chinese simplified than it is directly setting the **this.Text** value and than calling OnPreviewKeyDown , OnPreviewTextInput. Any suggestion please how to make logic independent of culture specific.

Xaml code is like:

```
           <External:TimePicker x:Name="StartTimePicker" InputMask="ii:ii" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    Validation.Error="StartTimePickerError" Text="{Binding Path=StartTime, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" Width="50"
                    ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource ={RelativeSource Self},Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
            </External:TimePicker>
```

It also throws **System.ExecutionEngineException** if it encounters **e.Key** under event **OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)**